# Problems getting Adsense to show up in Concrete5

Tags: adsense, concrete5

(I tried the C5 forums and the C5 IRC channel, but support is not too good)

Here is the problem regarding **Adsense**.

When I use Concrete5's **Edit Mode**, I can see the Adsense ads.

https://img.skitch.com/20110604-gshhqyej459hsw41jhwkqfc59m.jpg

When I **Exit Edit Mode**, they are blank for the front page.

http://premierclinics.net/

They do, however, work on a subpage, such as a product page. I cant use more than 2 hyperlinks, so you'd have to browse to a product to see it.

**Things I have done:**

- Waited 48 hours, as per Google's recommendations
- Tried multiple browsers, multiple OS', multiple computers
- Cleared cache (deep)

**Things I have not done:**

- Modify Google's Adsense code
- Added any Adsense plugins to Concrete5

This is a basic installation. I have simply added a HTML block and pasted the code directly from Google in the HTML editor block of the website. The code has not been tampered with by Concrete5 (as far as I know -- it shouldn't).

Answer (score 0):

Have you by any chance put the content in between the "isEditMode" condition?

```
<?php
global $c;
if ($c->isEditMode()) { 
   //Adsense code
}
?>
```

If so take it out of there :-)